# Android button place icon on top of it

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to place an image/icon on top of the button how can i reach that same as zindex in css. how can i reach that.

Below is a example of my layout file and xml file of the button.

### Layout File.axml

```
<Button
android:text="RTC Alarm"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30sp"
android:layout_width="270dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:background="@drawable/ButtonInfo"
android:shadowColor="#C4BEBE"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:shadowDx="0"
android:shadowDy="0"
android:shadowRadius="5"
android:layout_marginTop="10.1dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10.1dp"
android:id="@+id/btnAlA" />
```

### ButtonInfo.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/inzien"
android:width="40dp"
android:height="40dp"
android:left="0dp"
android:top="20dp"
/>
<item>
<shape>
<corners
android:radius="14dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="270"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#9C0009"
android:startColor="#C7000B"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="linear"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Have yout try `ImageButton`?

Comment: Button layout_height="80dp", layer-list android:height="40dp". This is your problem

Comment: Nope not working and im creating a shape but want a icon on top of my button

Comment: Again. Have you try use `ImageButton` instead of `Button`? ImageButton has property `src` which can be use to show drawable on top of button

Comment: Button have drawableTop attribute. Try in layout xml file.                              "" android:drawableTop="@drawable/blabla" ""

Comment: Can ya also center the android:drawableTop ? and also able to see the text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code in ButtonInfo.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="14dp"
            />
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerX="35%"
            android:centerColor="#9C0009"
            android:startColor="#C7000B"
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:type="linear"
            />
        <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp"
            />
        <size
            android:width="270dp"
            android:height="60dp"
            />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="#878787"
            />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_leader_board"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    />
```

You need to add upper layer at bottom, because z order maintained from bottom to top

Comment: Thnx ! thats what i asked for !